# MERGE/CREATE in neo4j UNWIND

Tags: neo4j

I have following data **(Info)** in **Neo4j Label**:

```
{
   domain:"domain1.com",
   email: "some01@email.com"
},
{
   domain:"domain2.com",
   email: "some02@email.com"
}
..................
..................
```

Now I want to insert data into **Info** if new domain is found, otherwise merge.

I've tried the following **CQL**:

```
 WITH [{domain:"domain1.com", email: "some@email.com"}, 
       {domain:"domain3.com", email: "some03@email.com"}] as arr

   UNWIND arr as ar
      MATCH (x:Info) WHERE x.domain = ar.domain
      WITH count(x) as c, ar
      CALL apoc.do.when( c <> 0, 
         'MERGE (a:Info {domain: ar.domain}) ON SET a.email=ar.email return a', 
         'CREATE (a:Info { domain: ar.domain, email: ar.email }) return a',
         { c:c, ar:arr }) YEILD value
       RETURN value
```

In above `CQL`, only merge is working, but nothing created.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up `ar` and `arr` all over the place here.

In your outer query `arr` is a list. Yet you pass `arr` in for `ar` in your `apoc.do.when()` call and treat it as a map (`ar.domain` and `ar.email` obviously won't work here within `apoc.do.when()`)

You're also referencing `arr.domain` and `arr.email` in the else part of `apoc.do.when()`, but `arr` isn't in scope.

You also don't need to pass `c` into the procedure call; the evaluation in the first argument uses the existing scope, only the queries after that require you to pass variables between scope.

Also `ON SET` isn't valid, you have to use `ON MATCH SET`, `ON CREATE SET`, or just `SET`.

All this said, you don't even need to use `apoc.do.when()`, it looks like you only need to use MERGE and SET:

```
WITH [{domain:"domain1.com", email: "some@email.com"}, 
       {domain:"domain3.com", email: "some03@email.com"}] as arr

UNWIND arr as ar
MERGE (x:Info {domain:ar.domain}) 
SET x.email = ar.email
RETURN x
```

Remember that MERGE is like a MATCH or CREATE (when no matches are found), so after the MERGE it will always be bound to a node, either an existing node or a newly created node, and since you want to set the `email` property in either case, we can just use SET here.